# Intellij IDEA Evaluate Expression window and Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() value

Tags: java, multithreading, intellij-idea

Due to unknown reasons i'm unable to get correct value of **currentThread().isInterrupted()** from **Intellij IDEA Evaluate Expression** window.

This is small code snippet that will help you to reproduce the same behaviour:

```
public class IsInterruptedTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
    }
}
```

To reproduce it, do the following steps:

1. Set up a breakpoint at `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());`
2. Start main method in a debug mode
3. Wait till execution reaches the breakpoint.
4. Call `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted();` from **Evaluate Expression window** (Alt + F8). (For me this call returns **false** value)
5. Resume program execution and once it is done -  check the value printed in console. (For me **true** is printed right here)

So, my question is - why these two values are different?

Is this happening due to current thread is being suspended by the debugger? If that so, is there any way to get correct value of `isInterrupted()` call from the **Evaluate Expression** window in the IDE?

Comment: What does Thread.currentThread() return when you are in the evaluation console? Is it different when you call it from test()?

Comment: No, it is the same thread instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known and not yet fixed bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-169706