# LockSupport.park() wakes up twice when debugging

Tags: java, multithreading, eclipse, intellij-idea

I am looking at this question [Why is the AQS printed differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69997805/why-is-the-aqs-printed-differently). In the process of solving, it was discovered that the problem with this question was actually in the debug mode, `LockSupport.park()` would wakes up twice in `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer#parkAndCheckInterrupt`.

Look at the following code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("begin park: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                LockSupport.park();
                System.out.println("end park: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                System.out.println(Thread.interrupted());  // print and clear interrupted status
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        thread.interrupt();
    }
```

Output is normal :

```
begin park: Thread-0
end park: Thread-0
true
begin park: Thread-0
```

And I set up a breakpoint at `System.out.println(Thread.interrupted());` , run this code in debug mode(this breakpoint will be triggered **twice**), and output will change to:

```
begin park: Thread-0
end park: Thread-0
true
begin park: Thread-0
end park: Thread-0
false
begin park: Thread-0
```

I'm using **Intellij IDEA(2019.1.3) and JDK8**. I'm wondering if this is a bug caused by IDE. I also found a little bit similar bug (it seems to be a bit related): [Intellij IDEA Evaluate Expression window and Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853591/intellij-idea-evaluate-expression-window-and-thread-currentthread-isinterrupte).

And I also downloaded **Eclipse(2021-09)** for testing, result is same as in `Intellij IDEA`. (By the way, the `Intellij IDEA` bug mentioned above is also reproduced in `Eclipse`.)
[image]

Is this a bug in IDE?

Comment: It doesn’t miss an interrupt, as it clearly printed `true` the first time it woke up. Since the interrupt flag is cleared by `Thread.interrupted()` as you even commented in the code, it will print `false` the next time it wakes up.

Comment: Maybe it’s also worth reminding that [`LockSupport.park()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#park()) allows *spurious wakeups*, so if it wakes up a second time for whatever JVM internal reason when a break point exists, it is all within the specification.